# Scrollview not start from top

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, scrollview

I have an activity that has a `ScrollView`, and for some reason when the activity loads, **it does not start from the top but somewhere in the middle.** I tried to work this out in the code but that was unsuccessful. I even tried in the XML by adding

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Since I have quite a few EditText in that Acitivity, but all attempts have been unsuccessful.

Below is the layout code:

```
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Update:
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.9"


    android:background="#ffffff" >

<RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="797dp" 
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tASearchDistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Profile Creation"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tSex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Upload your Profile Picture"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_below="@+id/texperience" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rimale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rifemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarDistance"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="50" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tAge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tAge" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rlmale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rlfemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tName4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvseekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvMinAge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarDistance"
        android:text="50"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Individual search distance "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="50" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conditions"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/disclaimer"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:text="Looking for"
        android:textColor="#3D3C3A"
        android:textColorHint="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texperience"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="I am a"
        android:textColor="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarActivityDistance"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sbseekBarDistance"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tName01"
        android:progress="50" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvseekBarActivityDistanceValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvseekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarActivityDistance"
        android:text="50"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tName01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvseekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Activities search distance"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tName4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMinAge"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Maximum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sbseekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/conditions"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMaxAge"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="Quick description about you"
        android:maxLength="50"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textColorHint="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvPaid4"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_bac2"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tName4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tName01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Minimum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMinAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="25"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMaxAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="50"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tProfileTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Welcome to Dooba. We provide you with a date for everything you want to do. To begin, please fill out all of the information below."
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#3D3C3A"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|left"
        android:onClick="pickPhoto"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Upload from device gallery"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvseekBarActivityDistanceValue"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvseekBarActivityDistanceValue"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your age here"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textColorHint="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:typeface="sans" >


    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/conditions"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sbseekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPaid1"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter your name here"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textColorHint="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPaid1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/conditions"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tProfileTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Profile Creation"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPaid4"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/texperience"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border_image"
        android:cropToPadding="true"

        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPaid4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sbseekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tSex"
        android:text="Upload your profile picture"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try this in activity: `myScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);`

Comment: remove android:layout_gravity="top|center" in scrollview and try

Comment: what these for?!! android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true". your scrollview is the root layout. not in relative layout to use layout_alignParentTop and not in frame layout to use layout_gravity

Comment: thank you much for your response. I still seem to have the same issue. I have updated my code and provide an update under my initial post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem causes by your `EditText` it has `focus` so you must remove `focus` from it;

in `onCreate`:

```
RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main); 

v.requestFocus();
```

if the above dose not work then for all of your EditText call `setFocusable(false);`

Update:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        ScrollView v = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollProfile); 
        v.requestFocus();


    }
}
```

and xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.9"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="797dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tASearchDistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Profile Creation"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tSex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Upload your Profile Picture"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_below="@+id/texperience" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rimale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rifemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarDistance"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="50" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tAge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tAge" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rlmale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rlfemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tName4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvseekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvMinAge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarDistance"
        android:text="50"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Individual search distance "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="50" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conditions"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:text="Looking for"
        android:textColor="#3D3C3A"
        android:textColorHint="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texperience"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="I am a"
        android:textColor="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarActivityDistance"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sbseekBarDistance"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tName01"
        android:progress="50" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvseekBarActivityDistanceValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvseekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarActivityDistance"
        android:text="50"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tName01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvseekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Activities search distance"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tName4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMinAge"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Maximum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sbseekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/conditions"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMaxAge"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="Quick description about you"
        android:maxLength="50"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textColorHint="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvPaid4"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#00FFFF"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tName4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tName01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Minimum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMinAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="25"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMaxAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="50"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tProfileTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Welcome to Dooba. We provide you with a date for everything you want to do. To begin, please fill out all of the information below."
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#3D3C3A"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|left"
        android:onClick="pickPhoto"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Upload from device gallery"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvseekBarActivityDistanceValue"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvseekBarActivityDistanceValue"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your age here"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textColorHint="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:typeface="sans" >


    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/conditions"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sbseekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPaid1"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter your name here"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textColorHint="#3D3C3A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPaid1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/conditions"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tProfileTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Profile Creation"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPaid4"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/texperience"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:cropToPadding="true"

        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPaid4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sbseekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tSex"
        android:text="Upload your profile picture"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thank you much for your response. I still seem to have the same issue. I have updated my code and provide an update under my initial post. Unfortunatetly setFocusable seems to have no effect

Comment: add this to your `RelativeLayout` `android:descendantFocusability=blocksDescendants` and for all `EditTex` `android:focusable =false`

Comment: thank you. this has brought the activity to the top, but now, the edittext has become unusuable, where when i can no longer type in them

Comment: with android:descendantFocusability=blocksDescendants, it brings it to top, but then all edittext becomes non-functional

Comment: If you have a listview inside a scrollview, then set the setFocusable(false); on the listview.

Comment: Why is this answer marked as correct answer? How you solved the problem with the edit texts not editable?

Answer (score 0):

Remove these attributes because ScrollView is the top view in your xml file

```
android:layout_gravity="top|center"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Also remove

```
<requestFocus />
```

In this TextView both padding and margin are provided check if you really need it.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tProfileTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Welcome to Dooba. We provide you with a date for everything you want to do. To begin, please fill out all of the information below."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />
```

Modify your RelativeLayout like this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="797dp" 
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">
```

Comment: thank you much for your response. I still seem to have the same issue. I have updated my code and provide an update under my initial post